# OSX Serial read freeze / hang

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, select, serial-port

I'm writing a serial communication wrapper class in Objective-C. To list all serial available modems and setup the connection I'm using pretty much the same code as used in [this example project by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWSerial/WWSerial_SerialDevs/SerialDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000384-TPXREF119).

I could read and write the ways apple does it. But I want to implement a loop on a second thread and write to the stream if a `NSString *writeString` longer 0 and read after write if bytes are available.

I got writing working quite straight forward. I just used the `write` function declared in `unistd.h`.

Reading will not work. Whenever I call `read()`, the function hangs and my loop does not proceed.

Here is the code used in my loop:

```
- (void)runInCOMLoop {
    do {
        // write
    } while (bytesWritten < strlen([_writeString UTF8String]));

    NSMutableString *readString = [NSMutableString string];
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    ssize_t readB = 0;
    char buffer[256];

    do {
        readB = read(_fileDescriptor, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this function hangs
        bytesRead += readB;

        if (readB == -1 {
            // error
        }
        else if (readB > 0) {
            if(buffer[bytesRead - 1] == '\r' ]] buffer[bytesRead - 1] == '\n') {
                break;
            }

            [readString appendString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]];
        }
    } while (readB > 0);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sending in any data?

Answer (score 1):

`read`() will block if there is nothing to read. Apple probably has their own of doing things, but you can use `select`() to see if there is anything to read on `_fileDescriptor`. Google around for examples on how to use select.

Here's one link on StackOverflow:

[Can someone give me an example of how select() is alerted to an fd becoming "ready"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625224/can-someone-give-me-an-example-of-how-select-is-alerated-to-a-fd-becoming-rea)

This excerpt from the select man is pertains:

```
     To effect a poll, the timeout argument should be
     non-nil, pointing to a zero-valued timeval structure.  Timeout is not
     changed by select(), and may be reused on subsequent calls, however it is
     good style to re-initialize it before each invocation of select().
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the non-blocking flag (`O_NONBLOCK`) on the file descriptor using `fcntl()` to keep `read()` from waiting for data, but if you do that, you have to continuously poll looking for data, which is obviously bad from a CPU usage standpoint. As Charlie Burns' answer explains, the best solution is to use `select()` which will allow your program to efficiently wait until there is some data to be read on the port's file descriptor. Here's some example code taken from my own Objective-C serial port class, [ORSSerialPort](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort) (slightly modified):

```
fd_set localReadFDSet;
FD_ZERO(&localReadFDSet);
FD_SET(self.fileDescriptor, &localReadFDSet);

timeout.tv_sec = 0; 
timeout.tv_usec = 100000; // Check to see if port closed every 100ms

result = select(localPortFD+1, &localReadFDSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
if (!self.isOpen) break; // Port closed while select call was waiting
if (result < 0) {
    // Handle error
}

if (result == 0 || !FD_ISSET(localPortFD, &localReadFDSet)) continue;

// Data is available
char buf[1024];
long lengthRead = read(localPortFD, buf, sizeof(buf));
NSData *readData = nil;
if (lengthRead>0) readData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:lengthRead];
```

Note that `select()` indicates that data is available by returning. So, your program will sit suspended at the `select()` call while no data is available. The program is *not* hung, that's how it's supposed to work. If you need to do other things while `select()` is waiting, you should put the `select()` call on a different queue/thread from the other work you need to do. `ORSSerialPort` does this.